# How to split string on forward slash in bash

Tags: string, bash, split

example String :

/gasg/string

expected result : `string`

Characters to  to remove: all characters between the "/" symbols including the symbols

Comment: `batween the "/" symbols` What should haapen if there is only one slash, or no slashes at all? Or text before the first slash?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

With `sed`:

```
$ echo "/gasg/string" | sed -e 's/\/.*\///g'
string
```

With buil-in bash string manipulation:

```
$ s="/gag/string"
$ echo "${s##/*/}"
string
```

Your strings look exactly like Unix pathnames. That's why you could also use the `basename` utility - it returnes the last portion of the given Unix pathname:

```
$ basename "/gag/string"
string
# It works with relative paths and spaces too:
$ basename "gag/fas das/string bla bla"
string bla bla
```

Comment: The first slash in the parameter expansion isn't necessary. The quotes on the assignment are necessary in this case, but you should use them for the expansion by habit.

Comment: I agree that the first `/` is not necessary but I've added it to illustrate the point.

Comment: Your strings look exactly like Unix pathnames. - Yeah, it was my intention to get the last partion of the given pathname and with the basename its just like "find -exec basename {} \; " which is brilliant for me! Thank you for the tip.

Comment: Please note that you have to drop the first slash for the string manipulation to work on URIs/URLs (e.g. `ftp:///documents/string.txt`).

Answer (score 46):

Also awk - use slash as separator and print last field

```
echo "/gas/string" | awk -F/ '{print $NF}'
```

Or cut - but that will only work if you have same number of directories to strip

```
echo "/gasg/string" |cut -d/ -f 3
```

Comment: Can you eleborate why `-f 3` ?

Comment: @mrgloom -f is the field id. e.g. 3 is the third field (index 2). If you used `-f 2` the result was gasg. for `-f 1` it was just an empty string because there is nothing infront of the first slash.

Answer (score 11):

you can use bash string manipulation

```
a='/gasg/string'
echo ${a##*/}
```